# Make WooCommerce products linked below their Tag URLs?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags

I have WooCommerce product tags configured to display tagged products under URLs like:

`https://example.com/tag-base/tag1/`  *-- Shows all products with `tag1`*

These pages work as expected to show all the products with a given tag.

**I would also like to products directly accessible via the tag hierarchy URLs, for each relevant tag for a product, e.g.:**

```
https://example.com/tag-base/tag1/my-unique-product-slug
https://example.com/tag-base/another-tag/my-unique-product-slug
etc.
```

The desired result is to have multiple valid URLs for a single product, via any of its relevant tags.

Currently this does not work - is it possible?